# MySQL AVG of Time with milliseconds

Tags: mysql, time, average

The create and insert data is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testTime` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `startTime` time(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endTime` time(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=40910 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testTime` (`startTime`, `endTime`) VALUES
('00:00:37.185', '00:00:32.141'),
('00:00:41.229', '00:00:32.255'),
('00:00:37.278', '00:00:23.548'),
('00:00:37.205', '00:00:28.479'),
('00:00:41.343', '00:00:25.354'),
('00:00:38.703', '00:00:38.645'),
('00:00:37.990', '00:00:32.182'),
('00:00:37.858', '00:00:36.589');
```

I can do sum, diff but got problems with average. I would use AVG function cause sometimes I will do calculations with several time columns. I try :

```
SELECT
id,
SEC_TO_TIME(startTime+endTime) TotalSum,
SEC_TO_TIME(startTime - endTime) Diff,
TIME_TO_SEC(AVG(SEC_TO_TIME(startTime + endTime))) AverageT            
FROM testTime
Group by id;
```

I need return values in '00:01:09.326' format. With Sum, diff working well but no idea how to do it with the avg.

AVG results should be:

```
00:00:34.663
00:00:36.742
00:00:30.413
00:00:32.842
00:00:33.348
00:00:38.674
00:00:35.086
00:00:37.223
```

Thank you

Comment: Try like this `SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(AVG(SEC_TO_TIME(startTime + endTime)))) AverageT `

Comment: Not at all because it return 00:01:09 and that could be confuse like 1 minute 9 seconds. Initial format is 00:00:37.185 and expected return value shoul be 00:00:01.090

Comment: How come the avg will be different for a single value? If you are going to check for a row by adding start & end time then the sum will be the average am i right?

Comment: sorry forget about the names of columns, I should call them s1, s2. Question is that I do not find the way to use avg with time(3) fields.

Comment: Please add your expected result

Comment: result expected shoul be:

`00:00:34.663
00:00:36.742
00:00:30.413
00:00:32.842
00:00:33.348
00:00:38.674
00:00:35.086
00:00:37.223`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `AVG()` if you wanted the average of the values of a column, but from your expected results I see that what you want is the average of `startTime` and `endTime` for each row.
So add `startTime` and `endTime` and divide by `2`:

```
SELECT
  id,
  SEC_TO_TIME(startTime + endTime) TotalSum,
  SEC_TO_TIME(startTime - endTime) Diff,
  SEC_TO_TIME((startTime + endTime) / 2) AverageT            
FROM testTime
```

Since `Id` is unique I don't see the need of `GROUP BY id`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnZwjDNhQF4gfTT77qHNiS/3).
Results:

```
| id  | TotalSum     | Diff         | AverageT        |
| --- | ------------ | ------------ | --------------- |
| 1   | 00:01:09.326 | 00:00:05.044 | 00:00:34.663000 |
| 2   | 00:01:13.484 | 00:00:08.974 | 00:00:36.742000 |
| 3   | 00:01:00.826 | 00:00:13.730 | 00:00:30.413000 |
| 4   | 00:01:05.684 | 00:00:08.726 | 00:00:32.842000 |
| 5   | 00:01:06.697 | 00:00:15.989 | 00:00:33.348500 |
| 6   | 00:01:17.348 | 00:00:00.058 | 00:00:38.674000 |
| 7   | 00:01:10.172 | 00:00:05.808 | 00:00:35.086000 |
| 8   | 00:01:14.447 | 00:00:01.269 | 00:00:37.223500 |
```

Results:

Comment: I would use AVG function but your solution is simple and clean. Thanks